# Identity 2.0 issues - MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity-2

I'm starting to use Identity in ASP .NET MVC 5 and I already have some questions

1) What is the function of the "Identity_UserId" column. In all tables that appear (UserRoles, UserLogins, and UserClaims), it is always "NULL".
It has an FK relationship with the Users table.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11781418/28696307-2c65235c-730b-11e7-8593-530f87c03ba2.JPG

2) Why **await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync (User.Identity.GetUserId())**; Always returns 0? I have a registered user and I have it linked to two external accounts (Facebook and Google)

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> ManageLogins(ManageMessageId? message)
    {
        ViewBag.StatusMessage =
            message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
            : "";
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (user == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        var userLogins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        var otherLogins = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes().Where(auth => userLogins.All(ul => auth.AuthenticationType != ul.LoginProvider)).ToList();
        ViewBag.ShowRemoveButton = user.PasswordHash != null || userLogins.Count > 1;
        return View(new ManageLoginsViewModel
        {
            CurrentLogins = userLogins,
            OtherLogins = otherLogins
        });
    }
```

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11781418/28696311-3163ccbe-730b-11e7-86bc-f611b6998fbd.JPG

Thx!

Comment: And yet you managed to add one more link ;)

Comment: @Soham i'm a hacker =.=. However delete the image because the method was poorly implemented, fix it, but still not working.